# Virtual memory and Resident memory on linux

Tags: linux

In linux, when I do 'top' it has a column for 'virtual memory' and 'Resident memory' for each process:

5648 hap497   20   0  101m  13m  11m S 90.4  0.9   0:44.79 automated_ui_te
  729 root      20   0 99004  46m 5004 S  1.0  3.0   9:24.59 Xorg

My  question is how does linux determine how much memory should be moved to virtual memory and  move to resident memory for each process?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

swappiness?
[here](http://www.linuxvox.com/2009/10/what-is-the-linux-kernel-parameter-vm-swappiness)

Comment: Link is broken. Really poor answer...two words.